# Run batch File using Java (space in arguements issue)

Tags: java, batch-file, escaping, space

I am trying to run a batch file from Java. The following works:

```
Process p1 = java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime().exec("D:\\Users\\xx\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Test1\\New folder\\batch.bat");
```

The following does not work:

```
Process p1 = java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime().exec("D:\\Users\\xx\\Desktop\\Jar Test\\New folder\\batch.bat");
```

The error I get is "Windows cannot find 'D:\Users\xx\Desktop\Jar'. Make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again."

Although there are spaces in both paths, for some reason the second one is not running. I have read numerous threads about escaping spaces, but none of the solutions there worked with me.

Note: I have tried to use process builder but I am also facing the same issue.

Comment: Try with `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("\"D:\\Users\\xx\\Desktop\\Jar Test\\New folder\\batch.bat\"");`

Comment: Use a `ProcessBuilder`...

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Process p1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"D:\\Users\\xx\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Test1\\New folder\\batch.bat"});
```

This form of exec() wont tokenize your input by spaces for you.

Comment: Recommended reading that explains this and dozens other pitfalls of using Runtime.exec() without the proper care: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html